# scala class constructor implicit paramaters are fields?

Tags: performance, scala, implicit

Do implicit parameters in a class constructor behave like regular parameters in a way that if they are referenced somewhere inside that class they automatically become fields ?

If so how to avoid that in this case:

```
class Triangle[@specialized T, V[_]](p1:V[T],p2:V[T],p3:V[T])(implicit ev: Addable[V[T]]){
   def someFuncThatUsesAddable(): Any = ???
}
```

If I need to create a lot of those triangles, each instance will contain reference to Addable resulting in increased memory use.

Comment: If too many references to a single object truly becomes a problem, you have bigger issues to worry about.

Comment: @wheaties, This is not what the issue is all about. Each instance of Triangle gets an extra field `ev`. That is what I want to avoid.

Comment: @Rulli of course a field will be created, how else could the object be used later when it's needed if you do not store it in a field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting question. I didn't know and I decided to check. I see a field  is created for each implicit parameter:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.{universe => ru}
class X
class A()
class B(val i: Int)
class C(val i: Int)(implicit x: X)

object Xc extends App {
  implicit val x = new X()

  def getTypeTag[T: ru.TypeTag](obj: T) = ru.typeTag[T]

  def allDecls(d: ru.MemberScope) = d.mkString("[", ",", "]")

  def printTypeInfo(typeA: ru.Type) =
      println(s"type ${typeA.typeSymbol} has ${typeA.members.size} 
               members. Declarations: " + allDecls(typeA.decls))

      printTypeInfo(getTypeTag(new A()).tpe)
      printTypeInfo(getTypeTag(new B(1)).tpe)
      printTypeInfo(getTypeTag(new C(1)).tpe)
  } 
}
```

The output:

```
type class A has 22 members. Declarations: [def <init>: <?>]
type class B has 24 members. Declarations: [val i: <?>,private[this] val i: <?>,def <init>: <?>]
type class C has 25 members. Declarations: [val i: <?>,private[this] val i: <?>,implicit private[this] val x: <?>,def <init>: <?>]
```

Comment: Yeah, I guess Triangle itself must use a typeclass pattern to get rid of those fields. Have a trait implementing all Triangle behaviour, then provide implementation for a particular simple class containing just three points of it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course, there would be no other way to do it (as @puhlen pointed out). As an alternative, you could move `ev` to methods which use it:

```
class Triangle[@specialized T, V[_]](p1:V[T],p2:V[T],p3:V[T]) {
   def someFuncThatUsesAddable(implicit ev: Addable[V[T]]): Any = ???
}
```

but note that this changes semantics: it requires that the `Addable` be in scope at method call site, not when you create the triangle.

As a side note, I wouldn't expect `@specialized` to be helpful at all when `T` by itself isn't used anywhere.